# Why "bundle install" try to install outdated version of gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm, bundle

I have different gemsets

```
> rvm gemset list
gemsets for ruby-2.0.0-p247 (found in /Users/kai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247)
=> (default)
   global
   rails4

> rvm gemset use rails4
Using ruby-2.0.0-p247 with gemset rails4

> rails -v
/Users/kai/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in `to_specs': Could not find 'railties' (>= 0) among 43 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Users/kai/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:307:in `to_spec'
    from /Users/kai/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `gem'
    from /usr/bin/rails:22:in `<main>'
    from /Users/kai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails4/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
    from /Users/kai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails4/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

and when I'm doing:

```
> bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Using rake (10.1.0) 
Installing i18n (0.6.4) 
Installing multi_json (1.7.9) 
Installing activesupport (3.2.7) 
Installing builder (3.0.4) 
Installing activemodel (3.2.7) 
Installing erubis (2.7.0) 
Installing journey (1.0.4) 
Installing rack (1.4.5) 
Installing rack-cache (1.2) 
Installing rack-test (0.6.2) 
Installing hike (1.2.3) 
Installing tilt (1.4.1) 
Installing sprockets (2.1.3) 
Installing actionpack (3.2.7) 
Installing mime-types (1.23) 
Installing polyglot (0.3.3) 
Installing treetop (1.4.14) 
Installing mail (2.4.4) 
Installing actionmailer (3.2.7) 
Installing arel (3.0.2) 
Installing tzinfo (0.3.37) 
Installing activerecord (3.2.7) 
Installing activeresource (3.2.7) 
Installing coffee-script-source (1.6.3) 
Installing execjs (1.4.0) 
Installing coffee-script (2.2.0) 
Installing rack-ssl (1.3.3) 
Installing json (1.8.0) 
Installing rdoc (3.12.2) 
Installing thor (0.18.1) 
Installing railties (3.2.7) 
Installing coffee-rails (3.2.2) 
Installing jquery-rails (3.0.4) 
Using bundler (1.3.5) 
Installing rails (3.2.7) 
Installing sass (3.2.10) 
Installing sass-rails (3.2.6) 
Installing sqlite3 (1.3.7) 
Installing uglifier (2.1.2) 
Your bundle is complete!
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
Post-install message from rdoc:
Depending on your version of ruby, you may need to install ruby rdoc/ri data:

<= 1.8.6 : unsupported
 = 1.8.7 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
 = 1.9.1 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
>= 1.9.2 : nothing to do! Yay!
```

But I have ruby 2.0! Why it doesn't install rails 4.0 and activesupport 4.0?

Comment: Can we see your Gemfile?

Comment: Sounds like you don't have Rails written in your gemfile

Answer (score 2):

`bundler` installs gems basing on two files:

1. `Gemfile.lock` strict versions saved during previous installation,
2. `Gemfile` loose version declaration from user.

when you generate `rails` project first `Gemfile` is generated with something like this:

```
gem 'rails', '~> 3.2'
```

after the file is generated `bundle install` is ran which generates `Gemfile.lock` in which strict versions of gems are recorded, from now on any succeeding call to `bundle install` will install only the versions saved in `Gemfile.lock`.

To update gems to newer versions:

1. check `Gemfile` for any version restrictions - that might prevent installing the versions you would like to get
2. run `bundle update <gem_name>` to update only this single gem and what is require for it - but minimalizing scope of the changes to the smallest possible set of changes.
3. run `bundle update` to update all gems to latest versions allowed in `Gemfile`

Answer (score 0):

`bundle install` or in short `bundle` does not install the latest gem unless you have left out the version in your Gemfile. e.g.

```
gem 'rails'
```

But usually this is not the case, we specify versions to prevent application from "crashing" when some gems are updated and we unknowingly run `bundle update`, or for that matter move application to say test or production servers.  Usually when adding a gem to Gemfile, we do:

```
gem 'rails', '~> 3.2.7'
```

Note the leading `~>` in the version number. This says: use rails gem between versions `3.2.7` and less than `3.3.0`.

In order for your bundle command to grab rails 4.0, you need to change that line to read either one of the following:

```
gem 'rails', '>= 3.2.7'
```

or

```
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
```

If you use `gem 'rails', '>= 3.2.7'` then your rails application will use the latest gem available in your system. Note that `3.2.7` is just an example I'm using here.  If you use `gem 'rails', '4.0.0'` then your rails application will use rails version 4.0.0.

Please note that this change might break your existing rails 3.2 application.